# How to hide action bar for fragment?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How can I hide action bar for certain fragment?
I have searched for the answer at stackoverflow, but I have only found a solution, which involves disabling action bar for main activity in android manifest. Since I need to disable action bar for one fragment, this is not an option.
Any ideas? Thanks.

EDIT: min API level is 7, sherlock is not being used

Comment: can you post the code of the main and other activities?

Comment: I have the assumption that, if you have to change the ActionBar, you probably need a Activity or a Dialog instead of a Fragment

Comment: If you are using `Navigation Component` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58027509/4859873

Answer (score 79):

If you are using AppCompatActivity (you should) then this is the solution that worked for me:

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

You can add this in onCreate(). The support fragment's getActivity() returns a FragmentActivity, and this does not contain the getSupportActionBar() method. Using just getActionBar() gives null-pointer exception if you have AppCompatActivity.

Comment: after using the .hide() action bar disappera but there is still a blank space created !!

Comment: Even i'm facing the same issue. ActionBar disappers but black space is created

Answer (score 26):

Put this code in fragment in which you want to hide toolbar...

```
 @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
}
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
}
```

Comment: This worked for me...  and also we have make sure the it imports...

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

Answer (score 9):

As it was already mentioned, actionbar may be hidden by `(requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.hide()` call.
If you want to show it in some of your fragments and to hide it in some other fragments, it may be convenient to apply default (for your case) visibility in `onViewCreated` of your Base fragment:

```
abstract class BaseFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        (requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.show()
    }
}
```

and to hide it in particular fragments:

```
class HiddenActionBarFragment : BaseFragment() {
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        (requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.hide()
    }
}
```

This solution is more flexible than using `onStart` - `onStop` for visibility change because during the transition `onStart` of a different fragment will be called earlier than `onStop` of the current fragment. So the next fragment won't be able to 'override' actionar visibility applied in `onStop` of the current fragment.

Answer (score 8):

`getActionBar().hide()` or `getSupportActionBar().hide()` (if using ActionBarCompat v7 lib).
Regards

Comment: using `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar`getting error (cannot resolve method)

Comment: but [link to docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#hide())

Comment: getActivity().getActionBar().hide();

Answer (score 8):

Hide actionBar using this in the required fragment.

```
getActivity().getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

And Show actionBar with this in your next fragment.

```
getActivity().getActionBar().show();
```

Answer (score 7):

Put `getSupportActionBar().hide()` before `setContentView` in the Activity that holds the fragments.

Also add this: `((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide()` in the fragments before inflating layout. This works if you are using this `ActionBarActivity`.It also removes my **lags** in hiding action bar

Answer (score 7):

You can simply put this into your Fragment Class createView method:-

```
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.player_fragment, container, false);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Answer (score 5):

Paste the code in the fragments before inflating the layout to  **SHOW Action Bar `**
//Kotlin statement

```
(activity as AppCompatActivity?)!!.supportActionBar!!.show()
```

Paste the code in the fragments before inflating the layout to **Hide Action Bar `**
//Kotlin statement

```
(activity as AppCompatActivity?)!!.supportActionBar!!.hide()
```

This works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you're like me and have one main Activity and several Fragments, you can add a listener to your NavController in the main Activity's `onCreate()` method.

For instance, I only wanted it hidden in my Login Fragment, so I used this (Kotlin):

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
    if (destination.id == R.id.loginFragment) {
        supportActionBar?.hide()
    } else {
        supportActionBar?.show()
    }
}
```

This avoids having to add the call to `show()` in all the Fragments in which you *do* want the ActionBar.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `getActivity().getSupportActionBar().hide()` in the `onCreate()` of the fragment you wish the ActionBar to be hidden in?

I am assuming you are not using `ActionBarSherlock`.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is for complex non-AppCompat applications that use native **ToolBar** when running Lollipop onwards and native **ActionBar** otherwise.

It assumes you want to hide the ActionBar whenever Fragments are visible.

Inside *onCreate()* in each of your Activities:

```
getFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            U.ABkk(this, getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());
        }
    }
);
```

OR (much better) inside a 'singleton' class that **implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks**

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(final Activity A, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    A.getFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            U.ABkk(A, A.getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());
        }
    });
}
```

Inside the utility class:

```
/** Show/hide ActionBar for  KitKat devices */
public static void ABkk(Activity A, int count) {
    if (lollipop()) return;     // No problem when using Toolbar
    ActionBar ab = A.getActionBar();
    if (ab==null) return;
    if (count==1) { ab.hide(); }
    if (count==0) { ab.show(); }
}

/** Return true if API 21 or greater */
private static boolean lollipop() {
    return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP;
}
```

Using *onActivityCreated()* is a solution that requires **no changes** to your Fragments or Activities!

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin solution:

Add this to your fragment's `onCreateView()`:

```
(activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.hide()
```

And add this to the fragment's
`OnDestroyView()`:

```
(activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.show()
```