# android hide toolbar in specific fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, toolbar

I have a problem that I don't know how to solve. How do you hide a toolbar in a specific fragment, I have already been searching around on the internet and what I found was communicating activity and fragment would solve it. But it doesn't work for me at all, here is my code:

main_activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements like_frag.OnHideToolbar{

....

public void onHidingToolbar(int position){
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if(toolbar == null){
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
        }else{
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
        }
    }
```

like_frag.java

```
public class like_frag extends Fragment {

    OnHideToolbar mCallback;
    Toolbar toolbar;

    public interface OnHideToolbar {
        public void onHidingToolbar(int position);
    }

    public void onAttach(Activity activity){

        try{
            mCallback = (OnHideToolbar) activity;
        }catch(ClassCastException e){
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + "error implementing");
        }
    }
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.swipefrag, container, false);

        toolbar = (Toolbar)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

thanks in advance.

> I have a drawer inside the toolbar.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21504088/how-to-hide-action-bar-for-fragment

Comment: tried it already but it doesn't work. Do I have to put it inside onCreate() or the onCreateView() of the fragment?

Comment: OnActivityCreated or onCreateView

Comment: like this inside onCreate() or onCreateView(): ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity).getSupportActionBar().hide();

Comment: it does not work, has anyone other ideas?

Comment: If you're using the AppCompat library, are you calling setSupportActionBar(Toolbar) in your Activity's onCreate() method?

Comment: Yes I called setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

Comment: Is there a problem when I call setsupportactionbar(toolbar);?

Answer (score 128):

Put this code in fragment in which you want to hide toolbar...

```
 @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
}
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
}
```

Comment: It worked perfect. I tried many answers in stackoverflow. But nothing worked. You saved my day. Thanks a lot. I also agree, this should be the correct answer.

Comment: This is awesome. Kept trying to call `setVisibility ()` on it from the fragment. `.hide()` and `.show()` work perfectly from within the fragment.

Comment: Beware of the flickering issue while using this! I lost my sleep for 2 days profiling my constraint layouts and bottom nav, checking for performance issues.

Comment: @nandu How did you solve it? Currently facing the same issues with a constraint layout and bottom nav, it keeps getting stretched up before resetting, which looks horrible.

Comment: @Big_Chair I think I solved it by removing it altogether and setting it where needed using
        (activity as AppCompatActivity?)?.setSupportActionBar(appbar)

Comment: For the sake of consistency, shouldn't we show the toolbar in `onPause()`? Or hide it in `onStart()`?

Answer (score 44):

In the fragment's `onCreate` method call:
`((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();`

 Replace `AppCompateActivity` with the activity class you used.

**Edited**:

You could simply use the `onResume` method to call `hide()` and the `onStop` method to call `show()` as suggested in some of the comments.

```java
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
}
```

Comment: This won't show toolbar again when leaving that fragment.

Comment: You need to show it: getYourActivity().getSupportActionBar().show();

Comment: As @ODAXY said , you need to call getYourActivity().getSupportActionBar().show(); on the fragment's  onDestroy() method. So that rest of the application behaviour is rolled back.

Answer (score 28):

If you are using the new [`Navigation Component`](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation), add this while setting up the toolbar

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller,
           @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
       if(destination.getId() == R.id.full_screen_destination) {
           toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       } else {
           toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       }
   }
});
```

And for Kotlin, you can do the following:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
    if(destination.getId() == R.id.full_screen_destination) {
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE)
        bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
        bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is the Android [official doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#listen_for_navigation_events) explaining `addOnDestinationChangedListener`

Comment: It is also worth noting for beginners to make sure you [remove the action bar before adding the toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515058/this-activity-already-has-an-action-bar-supplied-by-the-window-decor)

Comment: Hey. This is really a good solution. Because I need to hide the action bar and nottom navigation view on some of the child fragment

Answer (score 9):

Create an interface in the fragment and use it to tell the parent activity to hide the toolbar.

Add these lines to your fragment:

```
private OnEventListener listener;

public interface OnEventListener {

    void hideToolbar() ;
}

public void setOnEventListener(OnEventListener listener) {

    this.listener = listener;
}
```

After creating your fragment in the main activity add:

```
    myFragment.setOnEventListener(new MyFragment.OnEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void hideToolbar() {

            getSupportActionBar().hide();
        }
    });
```

Whenever you need to hide the toolbar execute:

```
listener.hideToolbar();
```

from inside your fragment.

Comment: Add some code to your post for a better answer quality.

Answer (score 8):

Just add these methods to the fragment where you want to diable the toolbar ,and also in the fragment's `onStop()` make it visible again.

```
 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

in  kotlin hide and show `supportActionBar` as follows:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.hide()
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.show()
}
```

and if you want to have your own custom toolbar, in `OncreateView` set:

```
//your Custom toolbar in xml
val toolbar = binding.toolbar
(activity as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply use   `supportActionBar?.hide()` or `supportActionBar?.show()`.
If you are using NavigationController:

```
 navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
        if (destination.id == R.id.loginSuccessFragment) {
            supportActionBar?.hide()
        } else {
            supportActionBar?.show()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just make sure to call this in `onPostCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)` and not `onCreate` or `onPostCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?)`

Comment: This hides the action bar, but when going back to other screens, the layouts are now positioned behind the action bar, shifted up.

Answer (score 3):

**Put this code in fragment in which you want to hide toolbar...**

Add this( ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();) in onCreateView or in onResume.

and do this in onDestroy()

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();}
```

Answer (score 2):

use `getSupportActionBar().hide();` and `getSupportActionBar().show();`  in lifeCycle methods

Comment: getSupportActionBar() is not accessible from Fragment. You need to call getActivity() and cast if needed.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try it.**

```
 @Override
public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller, @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
    if (destination.getId() == R.id.nav_dashboard){
        if (toolbar !=null){
           toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }else {
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```